# Discrete Math- Ways to order men and women in a circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is: In how many ways can you order 2 men and 5 women (when two of these women are married to the two men) in a round circle such that every men will sit next to his wife?

My calculation is: Lets say each couple is one entity. So we have 2 couples and 3 women. Now there are 5! ways to order them times 2! permutations of the positions of the first couple times 2! permutations of the positions of the second couple. So we have: 5!*2!*2! = 480.

But now we need to divide by 7 because it's a circle but how can we? 480/7 isn't a natural number?

Answer (score 1):

When it's ordering in a circle, think about it like this.

Set a person or a couple as a fixed point and order everyone else.
Therefore you will have

$(5-1)!*2!*2!$